# How to deny delete on a table for all users

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Within SQL Server 2005, is there a way, with a single statement, to deny delete on rows
in a particular table for all users of the database?

Comment: Even those with `db_owner` role?!

Comment: @OMG Ponies: it's ok, those users with the db_owner role can just revoke those permissions (or grant depending on the solution) :)

Comment: @Joshua: Yeah, I wonder why the OP wouldn't just grant the db_datareader role to the people who shouldn't have access, or create a custom role that specifically had been denied DELETE privilege to the table...

Comment: yes i tried public role but did not seem to work

Comment: everyone except db_owner really

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER yourTriggerName ON YourTableName
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS

    ROLLBACK
    RAISERROR('ERROR, DELETEs not permitted in YourTableName!!!',16,1)
    RETURN

go
```

working sample:

```
CREATE TABLE XYZ  (RowID int)
INSERT XYZ VALUES(1)
INSERT XYZ VALUES(2)
go 

CREATE TRIGGER yourTriggerName ON XYZ
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS

    ROLLBACK
    RAISERROR('ERROR, DELETEs not permitted in XYZ!!!',16,1)
    RETURN

go

delete XYZ
```

OUTPUT:

```
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure yourTriggerName, Line 6
ERROR, DELETEs not permitted in XYZ!!!
Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of extreme, but you can look at an [INSTEAD OF DELETE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191208.aspx) trigger to ignore the deletions. You could raise an error similar to 'delete access ... denied'

Obviously users with db_owner access privileges could drop the trigger

Answer (score 0):

if you want to row based restriction create a table (for lock) and insert ids of rows that you want to protect. and create a relation.

Answer (score 0):

**Only** triggers (or refactor your security/permission model)

One example where permissions won't help: If you have stored procs that delete rows, and both the proc/table have the same owner, table permissions will `not` be checked, even DENY. See [ownership chaining](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676(SQL.90).aspx). So users can delete or change data without any rights on the table at all.