# Deny read permission can be circumvented with a view?

Tags: security, sql-server-2000

Consider user is denied access to a table of financial secrets:

```
SELECT * FROM Transactions
SELECT permission denied on object 'Transactions'
```

No problem:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.Transactions2 AS SELECT * FROM Transactions
Command(s) completed succesfully.

SELECT * FROM Transactions2
(84,387,982 row(s) affected)
```

Are users supposed to be able to bypass `deny` permissions on a table by aliasing the table?

**Edit:** Sauce:
[image]

Comment: Is it awful, or is it views acting exactly like they were intended?

Comment: Let's be clear: 1. your users can create views? 2. Views are not table aliases: they are discrete objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working as advertised

It's called "[ownership chaining](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188676.aspx)"

- dbo owns both table and view/function/stored proc
- view/function/stored proc references table
- table permissions are *not* checked at all (for GRANT, DENY, whatever)

If you don't want someone to see a column/table, don't have it in the view/function/stored proc. Or add logic/joins to check permissions according to whatever model you've used.

Previous answers: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4107040/deny-read-permission-can-be-circumvented-with-a-view/4107191#4107191), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633012/how-to-deny-delete-on-a-table-for-all-users/3642473#3642473)

It's been in SQL Server and Sybase since, well, long time.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this *part of the intent of views* in the first place? To enable visibility to certain, specific information from tables when the user does not otherwise have select permissions on the underlying table(s)?

Sounds like the problem here is that the user in question has rights to create a view in the first place.

For example, say you wanted to expose the non-confidential information in that table; you could do that with a view that limits the results only to what you wanted to be seen.

Comment: i can certainly see the value in that (*please use the view rather than the table directly*). On the other hand i think you can see my concern.

Comment: No, not really. As gbn posted; it's working exactly as advertised. You just need to apply permissions correctly; Your user should not have permission to create views.

Comment: But you have to ask yourself, which is easier to accomplish? Denying read on the table that contains data - or going through every view, stored procedure and user-defined function in every database, hoping you find every reference. And even someone could edit any of the above. If this were the Windows NT security model, NTFS permissions, or Facebook privacy, the expected behavior would be "i want to block people from seeing this" To which the response is "that's fine, but they can still see it though this pair of glasses"

Comment: You just really need to study what the purpose of views is, I suppose. Understand what they are, and there's no confusion whatsoever.

Comment: Users should be allowed to create views of data they have permission to see.